# Is it parallel or series

Tags: rf, circuits

In the figure below, an RLC circuit, the author in the book says, that the resonant circuit sees Rs and RL to be parallel so he combined them (R total = the parallel sum of Rs and RL), is it right that is the current (Is ≠ IL ) so 
The two components are parallel?

[image]

Comment: Can you offer a direct quote from the book?  It would help to know exactly what the author meant.  It appears to me that \$R_{loss}\$ is in series to \$L\$, the pair of which are in parallel to \$C\$ and \$R_L\$, all of which are in series to \$R_S\$.  Assuming someone who went to the trouble to write a textbook is fairly intelligent, the context in which they are making the assertion is likely very relevant.

Comment: You should look from the resonant circuit's perspective, not the source's perspective, so remove/short the source...

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to find out the resistance seen by the LC tank. Here's what you can do:
[image]

So you need resistance between terminals A and B. Just disconnect the LC tank and disable/short the voltage source.

[image]

Thus the resistance seen by LC is parallel combination of Rs and RL.

Comment: That was helpful , thanks !